# Времена глаголов в стихах

Tags: грамотная-речь, глаголы, времена

Можно ли в стихах употребить глаголы с разным временем?

*Распустилась черемуха нежная,

Ароматом наполнила улицу,

На кудряшки свои белоснежные

Смотришь в зеркало маленькой лужицы...*

Comment: Вторая строка заканчивается запятой?

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать разные времена глаголов, разные сочетания совершенных/несовершенных глаголов -- как в стихах, так и в прозе. Делать это надо с умом, то есть, к примеру, "Я подошёл к дороге, по которой мчат автомобили" -- это плохо. У вас же всё нормально.

Но вот что нельзя -- так это внезапно прыгать из третьего лица во второе.
*Распустилась черемуха нежная,

Ароматом наполнила улицу* -- третье лицо.
*На кудряшки свои белоснежные

Смотришь в зеркало маленькой лужицы...* -- второе лицо.